# error in writing text to a file using node js fs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have a folder which is in my public folder called errorlogs.I want to append text to a file in that folder without overwriting the file. However, for some reason, I am unable to do that using the fs.appendfile. Please can someone suggest my error. Here is what I tried.It actually creates a file called  errorlogsapikey.txt outside my public folder which is not what I want

```
var filepath = __dirname+'/errorlogs';

ensureExists(__dirname + '/errorlogs', 0744, function(err) {
    if (err){

    } // handle folder creation error
    else {
        console.log("we are all good");
        var data = "url:" +"    "+url+"  "+"urlstatus:"+"   "+urlstatus+"   "+"time:"+ "   "+formatted;
        fs.appendFile(filepath + apikey+'.txt', data,function(err){
              if(err) throw err;
        });

    }
});

function ensureExists(path, mask, cb) {
    if (typeof mask == 'function') { // allow the `mask` parameter to be optional
        cb = mask;
        mask = 0777;
    }
    fs.mkdir(path, mask, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            if (err.code == 'EEXIST') cb(null); // ignore the error if the folder already exists
            else cb(err); // something else went wrong
        } else cb(null); // successfully created folder
    });
}
```

Comment: The issue is with your file path. check what is the file path you are providing for append? you need to generate correct path to append specific file.

Comment: Please do `console.log(__dirname)`. Undoubtedly you are not targeting the folder you think you are. You may need `var filepath = __dirname + 'public/errorlogs'`

Comment: `filepath + apikey + '.txt'` looks to me like it is missing a slash and needs to be `filepath + '/' + apikey + '.txt'` because the way you build `filepath`, it doesn't have a slash on the end of it.  Also, what is your public folder where you want this file to go?  It's not clear that you're actually building a path to the public folder.  `__dirname` will be the directory where this module file is located.